# Querying using a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure the title makes sense, but I have a `users` model and a `schedule` model. The `user` `has_many: schedules` and `schedule` `belongs_to: user`.

A Schedule is a model with a day, and start and end time. Essentially a user has many schedule objects for each time they are available (i.e. if they are free on Monday from 5am-10am the object will be `{day: 0, start: 5, end: 10}` (0 is Monday, 1 Tuesday, etc.)

I would like to query all users who (on a given day at any given hour) have a schedule object that contains that hour.

Something along the lines of `Users.where(user.schedule.day: params[:day], user.schedule.start < params[:start], user.schedule.end > params[:end])`.

Obviously this doesn't work and I can't figure out what this type of query is called to look for a good answer.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the where with a string instead of a hash, in order to be able to use the greater and less than conditions:

```
User.joins(:schedules).where('schedules.day = ? and schedules.start < ? and schedules.end > ?', params[:day], params[:start], params[:end])
```

`joins` will join the *schedules* table to the query. To access the columns of the schedules table you simply prepend 'schedules.' before the column name. The `?` are replaced by the arguments in order of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

```
# class Schedule
scope :for_day, ->(day) do
  where(day: day)
end

scope :falls_during, ->(start_hour, end_hour) do
  where("schedules.start > :start_hour", start_hour: start_hour).
  where("schedules.end < :end_hour", end_hour: end_hour)
end

# class User
scope :for_schedule, ->(schedule) do
  joins(:schedules).
  merge(Schedule.for_day(schedule[:day])).
  merge(Schedule.falls_during(schedule[:start], schedule[:end]))
end
```

Put it all together like

```
User.for_schedule(params)
```